# Concise output of failing tests in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

When I try to run RTL tests in Jest via:

```
yarn test some_file_path
```

Jest usually ends the output with "Summary of all failing tests" - where it mentions the path of the test file, the test name, the whole exception and usually a large JSX log where it says things like "unable to find any dom node with name x"...

The output becomes so large that we have to scroll through it and becomes hard to find in terminal or VS Code (and eventually leads to lines truncation)

Is it possible to get a simple concise summary of all failing tests along with test file paths but nothing else in the output - so that it's available in 15-16 lines max?